# Converting DB2 SQL query to SQL Server causing 'right function requires 2 argument(s)' error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the T-SQL version of this query. This is in DB2 version and I want to convert this to work in SQL Server.

```
UPDATE USERTEST
SET LOGIN = '5717-9889-' || LPAD(row_number() over(), 4, '0' ) || '@xxxx.com',
    EMAIL = '5717-9889-' || LPAD(row_number() over(), 4, '0' ) || '@xxxx.com'
WHERE LOGIN IN ('advw@12233318007262',
                    'caeqveewe',
                    'zxy@vdv',
                    'zstclair',
                    'zpasigna',
                    'zoe_tadvadv',
                    'zmadvadvadv',
                    'zadvadvadv',
                    'zielinsm@advadvadv.com',
                    'zhouxinhy',
                    'ZHEJIANG@BBAGGS',
                    'ZHE@avadvadv');
```

I have tried to write this using the `RIGHT` function. Then I got this error

> The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY

Then added the `ORDER BY` clause as shown here:

```
LOGIN = '5717-9889-' + RIGHT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LOGIN), 4, '0') + '@xxxx.com',
EMAIL = '5717-9889-' + RIGHT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMAIL), 4, '0') + '@xxxx.com'
```

And after doing this, I got this error:

> The right function requires 2 argument(s)

I'm not exactly sure what is the correct approach of writing this in SQL Server.

Any help would be appreciated

Below is the expected results I want in the table

```
LOGIN                         EMAIL 
-----                         -----
5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0003@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0003@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0004@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0004@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0005@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0005@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0006@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0006@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0007@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0007@xxxx.com
```

Comment: You pass in 3 arguments to the `RIGHT()` function. #1 : `row_number`, #2 : `4`, #3 : `'0'`

Comment: use [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to replace `LPAD` in `SQL Server`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the same order by in both locations, and cast the integer to varchar:

use a select to verify first:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT LOGIN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LOGIN) AS RowNumber
  FROM USERTEST
  WHERE LOGIN IN ('advw@12233318007262', 'caeqveewe', 'zxy@vdv', 'zstclair', 'zpasigna', 'zoe_tadvadv', 
                  'zmadvadvadv', 'zadvadvadv', 'zielinsm@advadvadv.com', 'zhouxinhy', 'ZHEJIANG@BBAGGS', 
                  'ZHE@avadvadv')
)
SELECT
      LOGIN = '5717-9889-' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(CTE.RowNumber AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + '@xxxx.com'
    , EMAIL = '5717-9889-' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(CTE.RowNumber AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + '@xxxx.com'
FROM USERTEST U
JOIN CTE ON U.LOGIN = CTE.LOGIN
```

If OK, then:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT LOGIN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LOGIN) AS RowNumber
  FROM USERTEST
  WHERE LOGIN IN ('advw@12233318007262', 'caeqveewe', 'zxy@vdv', 'zstclair', 'zpasigna', 'zoe_tadvadv', 
                  'zmadvadvadv', 'zadvadvadv', 'zielinsm@advadvadv.com', 'zhouxinhy', 'ZHEJIANG@BBAGGS', 
                  'ZHE@avadvadv')
)
UPDATE U
SET
     LOGIN = '5717-9889-' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(CTE.RowNumber AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + '@xxxx.com'
   , EMAIL = '5717-9889-' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(CTE.RowNumber AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + '@xxxx.com'
FROM USERTEST U
JOIN CTE ON U.LOGIN = CTE.LOGIN
```

| USERID | LOGIN | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | A | A |
| 12 | 5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com | 5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com |
| 13 | 5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com | 5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/caJjZ5Ws)

Comment: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
 https://dbfiddle.uk/dH_9CuPa

Comment: I have corrected that by using a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You can get incremented ids using `row_number()`, and adding leading zeros to those integers using [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function :

In this query, I assumed you had a unique column called `USERID`, but you can order by any column you want.

```
UPDATE u
SET u.LOGIN = '5717-9889-' + FORMAT(s.rn, '0000' ) + '@xxxx.com',
    u.EMAIL = '5717-9889-' + FORMAT(s.rn, '0000' ) + '@xxxx.com'
FROM USERTEST u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT LOGIN, row_number() over (order by USERID) AS rn
    FROM USERTEST
    WHERE LOGIN IN ('advw@12233318007262',
                    'caeqveewe',
                    'zxy@vdv',
                    'zstclair',
                    'zpasigna',
                    'zoe_tadvadv',
                    'zmadvadvadv',
                    'zadvadvadv',
                    'zielinsm@advadvadv.com',
                    'zhouxinhy',
                    'ZHEJIANG@BBAGGS',
                    'ZHE@avadvadv')
) as s on s.LOGIN = u.LOGIN
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vwZ3Bf9m)